# Master Scripts not Running during silent run of a database installer

Tags: windows-installer, silent-installer, advanced-installer

I have a database installer designed using Advanced Installer software. Though I don't face any problem while creation of all the databases, tables, stored procedure, functions, etc. during silent install, but the problem is with my master data scripts that are used to fill in some of the master tables. Some of those master scripts are not executing whereas some do execute. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The scripts have an execution condition, make sure the ones not executing have the correct condition set. Also, check the condition of their connection, if you have them placed under different database connections.

Comment: I don't think connection is a problem because thought we have different databases but all of them use the same connection string. So, I guess that is out of the question. But  yes, I need to have a look at the verbose log to see for the execution conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the scripts aren't in the InstallUISequence, just to state the obvious - they won't run during a silent install. Install your MSI and create a verbose log to see what's going on.

Comment: The SQL built in support from AI runs the scripts only on ExecuteSequence, so that should not be a problem. However, AI gives the users the option to set independent conditions on each script and select if the scripts should run on install, uninstall or maintenance.

Comment: I want the scripts to be run on install. And as far as the execution condition is concerned, can I get all that information in the Verbose Log? Is there any tool that can help me go through the verbose log? or doing it manually is the only option?

Comment: Get hold of Orca, the MSI file editor/viewer and see if you can identify the custom actions. They'll be in the CustomAction table and will appear in the InstallExecuteSequence table (sort by sequence) where you will see the condition for if they will run. Doesn't Advance Installer describe or show when they will run?

Comment: It does..Actually my custom actions are not part of either InstallUISequence or InstallExecuteSequence, they are executed as part of dialog editor.